# Angular form validation how to show error message on submit

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a form as follows :

```
<form [formGroup]="editProfileForm">
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First" formControlName="firstName [(ngModel)]="profileDetails.first_name">
    <small class="text-danger" [hidden]="editProfileForm.controls['firstName'].valid || (editProfileForm.controls['firstName'].pristine && !submitted)">First name Required</small>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last" formControlName="lastName" [(ngModel)]="profileDetails.last_name">
    <small class="text-danger" [hidden]="editProfileForm.controls['lastName'].valid || (editProfileForm.controls['lastName'].pristine && !submitted)">Last name Required</small>
    <button class="save-changes-btn" [disabled]="(!editProfileForm.valid)" (click)="saveDetails();">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

and the editProfile is defined in the component file as

```
this.editProfileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: [_.get(this.profileDetails, 'first_name', ''), Validators.required],
    lastName: [_.get(this.profileDetails, 'last_name', ''), Validators.required],
});
```

Now I need to show the validation messages on clicking the submit button. Here now I have disabled the submit button if, the form is not valid. But it will not show the error messages near to the corresponding fields and this will makes the user thinks that the there is nothing happening. How can I trigger the error messages to show near corresponding input fields ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do something like this.

First remove the disabling logic in the submit button.

**In component template.**

```
<form [formGroup]="editProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group block" [ngClass]="{'has-error': submitted && (editProfileForm.controls.firstName.errors)}">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
    <p>
      <span *ngIf="submitted && editProfileForm.controls.firstName.errors?.required">First name is required</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  // other controls
</form>
```

**In component class**

```
public onSubmit(): void {
  this.submitted = true;
  if(!this.editProfileForm.valid) {
    return;
  }

  // make the submitted variable false when submission is completed.

}
```

you can remove following part if you need to.

```
[ngClass]="{'has-error': submitted && (editProfileForm.controls.firstName.errors)}"
```

It will add css class to the element when the form control is invalid and submitted.

Comment: This construction `editProfileForm.controls.firstName.errors?.required` is not very well written , since the get() method is used to access form controls, the hasError() method is also used for errors. Better use `editProfileForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')`

Comment: Instead of adding a new property to your class you can add a template variable on your form and use it to check if the form was submitted. This solution is described by [this post](https://netbasal.com/show-form-errors-on-submit-in-angular-a6a10cd3e04b)

Comment: thank you ! i was facing that issue and solved it thanks to your answer !

Answer (score 27):

When saving, if the form is not valid, simply call `markAllAsTouched()` on the form group.

```js
saveDetails() {
  if(!this.editProfileForm.valid) {
    this.editProfileForm.markAllAsTouched();
  }
}
```

Comment: for me this sounds pretty logic.

Comment: I logged in only to upvote this answer. This should be marked as answer and proper way to show errors after submit.

Comment: Perfect, bingo :)

Comment: doesnt work for child components with form from parents

Comment: Small side-note: There is also a `invalid` property on forms which makes reading the code easier: `if(this.editProfileForm.invalid) {`

Answer (score 9):

Use `showValidationMsg()` method and pass the form group as parameter inside submit button method:

```
showValidationMsg(formGroup: FormGroup) {

    for (const key in formGroup.controls) {
        if (formGroup.controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const control: FormControl = <FormControl>formGroup.controls[key];

            if (Object.keys(control).includes('controls')) {
                const formGroupChild: FormGroup = <FormGroup>formGroup.controls[key];
                this.showValidationMsg(formGroupChild);
            }

            control.markAsTouched();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly for me with Angular Material and FormGroup. thank you!